# Ranorex to read data from an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: ranorex

I have an Excel spreadsheet with lots of data that needs to be entered to a desktop app.I do not want to manually type in all this information because it can take me forever to do that. Is there a way i can make a recording on ranorex for only one row (first row) of data and somehow instruct Ranorex to follow what i did on the first row to load the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't very clear, so I'll try to answer what I think you're asking.

Ranorex has built-in support for working with Excel spreadsheets.

Basically, you need to create a data source that uses your Excel spreadsheet file. Ranorex will then be able to map the values in each row to module variables. You can find the Data Sources dialog by right-clicking on a Test Case in the rxtst file.

Ranorex will automatically rerun the test case for each row in the spreadsheet. You can limit it, if you want, to just the first x number of rows in the Data Sources dialog.

You can find a lot more info about this on Ranorex's User Guide in the [Data-Driven Testing Lesson](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-3-data-driven-testing.html).